# How to pass Javascript variables inside a URL? AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

i am trying to pass the values of accesstoken and pageid inside the url that i use. Any ideas how to do it correctly?

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function makeUrl() {
    var accesstoken = "12345679|bababashahahhahauauuaua";
    var pageid =  "<?php echo $page_id;?>";
 $.ajax(
  {
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/?pageid/?access_token='+pageid+accesstoken,
 statusCode: {......
```

Comment: Why not use the [Facebook JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/?pageid/?access_token='+pageid+accesstoken,
```

to

```
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/?pageid='+pageid+'&access_token='+accesstoken,
```

Comment: Hi,i still facing a problem to pass the pageid var inside the ajax. I am taking an error message at the console
 """GET XHR https://graph.facebook.com/ """ 
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the "data" setting.  This will convert it to a query string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function makeUrl() {
    var accesstoken = "12345679|bababashahahhahauauuaua";
    var pageid =  "<?php echo $page_id;?>";
 $.ajax(
  {
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/',
    data: 'pageid='+pageid+'&access_token='+accesstoken
 statusCode: {......
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 'https://graph.facebook.com/?pageid='+pageid+'&access_token='+accesstoken
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your url using:

```
function makeUrl() {
  var accesstoken = '12345679|bababashahahhahauauuaua';
  var pageid =  'example'
  return 'https://graph.facebook.com/?pageid=' + pageid + '&access_token=' + accesstoken;
}
```

And then pass it to your AJAX function.

```
function doAjax(_url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: _url,
    type: 'GET'
  });
}

doAjax(makeUrl());
```

And now an elegant way to handle your success callback:

```
doAjax(makeUrl()).success(function() {
  // this will be executed after your successful ajax request
});
```