# How to pass a javascript variable in an ajax url?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a variable as per below:

```
var myip;
```

And I want to insert it in the url below:

```
$.ajax('http://api.ipstack.com/**[myip]**?access_key=mykey')
```

If I manually put in my ip in place of [myip] it gives me the desired results but I want to automate it.

I tried with the methods given in the url below but it didn't help.

[How to pass Javascript variables inside a URL? AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321402/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-inside-a-url-ajax)

Thanks in advance for going through and helping!

Comment: `var ip = 'yourip'; $.ajax('http://api.ipstack.com/' + ip + '?access_key=mykey')`...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass Javascript variables inside a URL? AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321402/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-inside-a-url-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use string template.**

```
$.ajax(`http://api.ipstack.com/${myip}?access_key=mykey`)
       ^                       ^^^^^^^                 ^
```

**Or using string concatenation.**

```
   $.ajax('http://api.ipstack.com/' + myip + '?access_key=mykey')
```

Comment: beware of compatibility though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility